# Constructor Not Working

Tags: c++, constructor

I am writing a program to show Conway's Game of Life in C++. My professor has given us a main function and a class describing the "universe", we must implement the functions prototyped in the class. My issue right now is actually getting the constructor to function. I will post the class, followed by what I have written for the constructor. Using GDB when I get to the first line that the constructor is used (universe(width, height, wrap);) I get the following error: libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007fff876fad46 in __kill ()

Any help is appreciated! Code below.

```
    // Conways game of life

    class universe {             
private:
int* array;     // A pointer to a [width]X[height] array of cells that constitutes       the universe
                //    for the game of life. A value of 1 signifies a live cell at that location.
int width;      // The width of the universe.
int height;     // The height of the universe
int wrap;       // wrap = 1 means the universe wraps around on itself -- the right hand 
                //   side connects to the left and the top connects to the bottom.
                //   wrap = 0 means the universe ends at the array boundaries.
public:
universe();         // A null constructor: sets array, width, height, and wrap to 0.
universe(int,int,int);  // Constructor to allocate space for a universe of given width (first value) 
                    //    height (second value) and wrap setting (third value). Sets all cells to 0.
void display();     // Display the live cells in a graphics window.
void setup();       // Display the universe then allow the user to interactively modify 
                    //    the cell arrangement using the mouse.
void operator<<(char*); // Read in a universe from a file; first number has the width,
                            //    second number is the height,
                            //    third number is the wrap parameter,
                            //    then 1s/0s in a 2D integer array represent living/dead cells.   
void operator>>(char*); // Save the universe to a file with the specified name (format as above).
void operator=(universe);   // Copy the contents of one universe to another.
void operator<<(universe);  // Calculate the new generation by applying the rules, then
                            //    display the new generation.
int neighbors(int,int);     // Returns the number of neighbors of the cell at i,j.
int value(int,int);        // Returns the value at cell i,j (0 or 1).
void setvalue(int,int,int); // Sets the value of the cell at i,j.  
void free(); // Release the memory used to store the universe. Set array = 0. 
};

// Implementation


universe::universe(){
array =0;               
width = 0;
height = 0;
wrap = 0;
}

universe::universe(int width1,int height1,int wrap1){

int i=0, j=0;
int* array = new int[width*height-1];       
for(i=0;i<width;i++){
    for(j=0;j<height;j++){
        array[j*width+i] =0;
                        }
                    }
width = width1;
height =height1;
wrap = wrap1;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a copy constructor and a destructor (a `free()` functions does **not** cut it). Also, I would suggest a container, but I'll bet you're not allowed to use it.

Comment: Do you see the 3-param constructor that allocates a local array (and never assigns it, thus leaking it) your **members** `width` and `height` *before* they are actually assigned? When that ctor is finished, you have an indeterminate value for `array`, a memory leak of undefined size, and width+height values assigned.

Comment: You should read through some articles/books on C++.  This code is like some grotesque love child of C and C++. RAII, containers, and initialization lists are your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many things wrong with the original code is it hard to just rattle off the list, but I can try:

1. Members `width` and `height` are used for member allocation sizing before they even contain definite values. Therefore their value usage is indeterminate, and therefore the memory allocation exhibits **undefined behavior**.
2. The allocation is being stored to a local pointer, then promptly lost after exiting the constructor. it is never assigned to the *member variable* `array`. Thus you are leaking memory. Further , since `array` (the member) is never assigned, its value is indeterminate even after construction, and therefore any access (read or write) using the address it contains is **undefined behavior**.
3. You have no class destructor to clean up the memory allocated in the constructor or member functions. (assuming you properly fix the 3-param constructor and it actually *saves* the memory allocation pointer in the `array` member). Therefore this leaks memory on destruction (assuming the 3-param constructor is fixed), or on construction (assuming the 3-param constructor is NOT fixed).
4. You're `width` and `height` members can currently accept negative values, which would make no sense to actually use, and would wreak potential havoc with your allocation. All members not intended to explicitly *allow* negative values should be of unsigned types, `size_t` being common.
5. Neither constructor has an initializer list. They both should.
6. `class universe` dynamically allocates memory for a local member variable. Without establishing a virtual destructor, copy-constructor, and assignment operator, compiler-default implementations will be provided, and they will most-assuredly cause either memory leaks or memory corruption as a result. This code should practice **[The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))**, and currently does not.
7. Your current allocation size logic in the 3-param constructor is off by one element. the (-1) does not belong there, and the loops immediately after will write one element beyond the allocated size as-written. This is **undefined behavior**.
8. You're using the name of a standard library defined class as the name of locally defined variable/class/member. While not officially "wrong" it is *highly suggested* you avoid this practice.

I *strongly* advise a [solid C/C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: This is a great post!

Comment: Thank you so much! I realize that I have a long ways to go with c++ and this assignment is frustrating (we are not allowed to edit the universe class or the main function). I realized after posting the issues 1, 2 and 4 which I have fixed. I am working through 3,5,6 and 8 (reading some literature) but I am pretty sure I am correct with regards to 7. I am allocating a 1D array that will contain a index for every data point in a hypothetical [width][height] grid.  If width is 5 and height is 10 width*height=50, however to create 50 indexes  I want to allocate an index of size 49.

Comment: Regarding your sample size (5x10), **you want 50 nodes (5*10).** They're *accessed* using indexes 0..49, but you still want 50. Don't confuse node count with maximum index used to access them. The former is always one *more* than the latter. If you want a 5x10 matrix, you need 50 nodes, **not** 49. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ConnorDurkin No worries at all. The math part of your (row,col) indexing is correct. `row*width + col` is standard part and parcel for implementing a row-major array in linear form, which is how most compilers I've ever used do it anyway. So you're on the right path for how it is laid out. Just a little off on the math and the C++ language stuff. It comes with time. Stick to it. Its a *beautiful* language that can be just amazing if you know how to use it, and some of the people on this board (not I) are near-unbelievable in the expert knowledge of what it is capable of.

Answer (score 2):

```
int* array = new int[width*height-1];
```

should be

```
array = new int[width*height-1];
```

since `array` is your class member, you should not declare a local variable with the same name again. Otherwise, you are not initializing the class member `array`. Local variable will hide class member.

Meanwhile, you should first assign values to `width` and `height` before using them with `new`.

Your codes  should look like the following:

```
 universe::universe(int width1,int height1,int wrap1){
    width = width1;
    height =height1;
    wrap = wrap1;
    array = new int[width*height-1];       
    for(int i=0; i<width; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<height; j++){
         array[j*width+i] =0;
      }
    }
}
```

Better to put member `int*array` after `wrap` if you would like to initialization list.